# Use only the digits $0-6$, how many $4$ digit numbers are there if:?

Tags: combinatorics

1. No repetition allowed?
2. Repetition is allowed?
3. The number must be odd, no repetition allowed?
4. The number must be between $3,000$ and $5,000$ AND EVEN, with no repetition allowed?

Comment: Edit the question to include your attmpts of solution.

Comment: what have you done so far? is it your assignment problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you can select the first number in $6$ ways, the second in $6$ ways, the third in $5$ ways, and the fourth in $4$ ways, and by the using fundamental principle of counting, there should be $6*6*5*4=720$ numbers (part 1)

For part 2, you can select first number in $6$ ways, the second in $7$ ways, the third in $7$ ways, and the fourth in seven ways. Hence, there should be $6*7*7*7=2058$ numbers.

For part 3, you can select fourth number in $3$ ways, first number in $5$ ways, second number in $5$ ways and third number in $4$ ways, there should be $3*5*5*4=300$ numbers.

For part 4, you can select fourth number in $4$ ways, first number in $5$ ways, second number in $5$ ways and third number in $4$ ways, there should be $4*5*5*4=400$ numbers.